# How to speed up numpy copy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy, numpy-ndarray

Does anyone know a faster alternative for the following python statement:

```py
img7[:, :, :, -12:] = img6.copy()
```

For context, `img7` is a 1920x17x20x16 numpy array of zeros, and `img6` is a 1920x17x20x12 numpy array.

Comment: How long does it takes and how fast is your RAM ? Memory operation are usually slow (except in cache).

Comment: I see no need to use `.copy()` explicitly. Omitting `.copy` speeds up by ~2x on my machine (33.2ms vs 17.0ms, with float64 using `numpy 1.21.6`).